# Stdin/Stdout redirection , input not working

Tags: c, cmd, stdout, pipe, stdin

I am trying to create a pipe between a command line shell and my application.

This is the code I have so far:
http://pastebin.com/uupd4aXi

What I am trying to do is write "whoami" to stdin and get a return equivalent to that command.
If I comment out the writeinput function, readoutput successfully prints the standard cmd printout. However if I don't, writeinput gets stuck at an infinite loop at:

```
for (;;) 
    { 

        bSuccess = WriteFile(hSTD_IN_WRITE, chBuf, sizeof(chBuf), &dwWritten, NULL);
        if ( ! bSuccess ) break; 
    }
```

If i remove the if statement and manually cause a break on the loop, I am still only getting the cmd printout message but not the respone to my command "whoami".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into the trap of [redirecting both stdin and stout but processing them serially](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx).

If all you want to do is run the `whoami` program and capture the output, then you don't need `cmd.exe` and try to pump `whoami.exe` as its input. Just run `whoami.exe` directly and capture its output.

EDIT: updated link to the article:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110707-00/?p=10223

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately the command "whoami" was just an example, so I can't just run whoami.exe, what will happen if i want the result of "echo 1" lets say. That article sais to use buffering but, I don't exactly get what is means, can you help me on that

Comment: `cmd.exe /c echo 1` will run the command without requiring you to pump data in via stdin. It also gets rid of the banner, so two birds with one stone.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working finally. While this seems to me like a workaround it certainly does the job. I would be curious however to find the 'proper' way of doing it

Comment: See the "to avoid this problem" paragraph at the end of the article.